# How to dispose object context in repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-4

I implemented a repository pattern to my application dat .

I have :

```
public class EFRepository<T>
{
    DbContext // My db context

    public IQureable<T> GetQuery()
    {
        DataContext.CreateQuery(...);
    }
}
```

Now let say I have user repository :

public class UserRepository : EFRepository
{
        public UserGetUserDetails(int userId)
        {
            GetQuery().Where(u=>u.Id = userId).First();
        }
}

my problem is how to release the `DbContext` when I use the EF repository in derived repositories. 
Lets say : `UserRepository: EFRepository` , and it uses the `GetQuery` then I have to dispose the context.

Any good idea how to make this in generic repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about what [unit of work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) you have. (there are many other tutorials on the internet). The idea is to keep the *same* dbcontext and to re-use it while being in the same unit of work. This way, entities will already be attached to the context when needing them, etc..

Now, this being a web application, your unit of work would be in this case a request. While in the same request, reuse your DBContext. There are many ways to do this and just off the top of my head - you will want something like 'OnActionExecuting' where you take care of your context.

But even better would be to use an Inversion of Control pattern (there are many frameworks out there that use this, i primarily use [NInject](http://www.ninject.org/) . This will automatically create a new instance of a certain class, when needed, depending on the scope you suggested - in this case 'onRequestScope'. A lot more to say about IoC but not the scope of the question

Comment: Thank you very much , actually this what u did , I used the unity IOC , they have a perexecutelifetimemanager , which mean to share an instance for the same request . Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar pattern in the past and in my case I actually inherited from `DbContext`, which itself implements `IDisposable`. Provided you are using `EFRepository` or classes derived from it in a `using` block you should be fine.

If you would prefer a `DbContext` member variable, then `EFRepository` will need to implement `IDisposable` and call `DbContext.Dispose()` from its `Dispose` method.

Comment: Thanks . But I have an issue . In any method I add to my repository which derive from EfRepository , use the get query instead of the context , and the get query uses the context , so how can use the dispose here .

Comment: Could you perhaps update your question with an example of what you are doing in this case?